# Postman API testing Framwork tests[] = true what does it do?

Tags: javascript, postman

Given these js lines from a collection that i got:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["The apple collor is= "+data.query] = true;
tests["The Country is "+data.countryCode] = true;
tests["User name is "+data.timezone] = true;
```

What does this do exactly?
This "tests" keyword, i could not find much on the web, does this test anything or what's the logic with this?

"tests" is not defined in preqreuesits Script or in the current script it is just called it seems like a map I assume?

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Did you look at the Postman learning center? https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/#previous-style-of-writing-postman-tests-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `responseBody` is in `JSON` format.

For example

```
'{"query":"something","countryCode":"123","timezone":"US"}'
```

So `JSON.parse()` will parse it to object.

```
{ query: 'something', countryCode: '123', timezone: 'US' }
```

Here it will contact the string with the data object value

```
let tests = {}
tests["The apple collor is= "+data.query] = true;
tests["The Country is "+data.countryCode] = true;
tests["User name is "+data.timezone] = true;
```

So the `tests` Object will look like

```
{
   "The apple collor is= something": true,
   "The Country is 123": true,
   "User name is US": true,
}
```

Comment: Hmm, yes I assumed this much, but I cannot find where that "tests" variable is defined, and it seems that whatever the "tests" variable has in the end, it displays it in the "test Results" section 

And if i do something like `tests["The sky is blue"] = false;`

In the Test Results, it will raise an assertion error `AssertionError: expected false to be truthy`

Which does not make sense to me

Comment: It's a keyword build into the sandbox, it's also the older syntax that was used before version 5. We've moved to use `pm.test` in the scripts now but kept the old syntax in place for backwards compatibility. https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/